# Dynamically returning conditions within variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

What is the best way to manipulate the below expression based off a given condition? E.g.

```
rtnData = (
  $(this).find('span').text().match(regEx[1]) &&
  $(this).find('span').text().match(regEx[2]) &&
  $(this).find('span').text().match(regEx[3]) 
);
```

Regex 2 or 3 may or may not be available in each case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be like this. This will not impact even if you don't have a particular item in regEx array

```
var rtnData = true;
var component = $(this);
regEx.forEach(function(currentRegEx) {
  rtnData = rtnData && component.find('span').text().match(currentRegEx)
});
```

Comment: I cannot seem to get this to work for me. The one below works well, but I would like to be able to have 4, 5, 6, etc in the future. Also, not sure what "result" pertains to.

Comment: Sorry, last moment change in variables. It should be alright now

Comment: Works nicely. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
var text = $(this).find('span').text()
rtnData = (
  text.match(regEx[1]) &&
  (!regEx[2] || text.match(regEx[2])) &&
  (!regEx[3] || text.match(regEx[3])) 
);
```